# How to Append a POINT to a MULTIPOINT column

Tags: postgis, coordinates, update, multipoint, st-union

I have a table in postgresql that includes a `geometry(MultiPoint,4326)` column.

I want to run a process that appends a new `MULTIPOINT(4.49306 52.26167)` to this column. I am currently doing this:

```
UPDATE foo SET multipoint_col = (SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Union(ST_AsText(multipoint_col::geography), 'MULTIPOINT(4.49306 52.26167)' ))) WHERE id=2749811;
```

This is not working all the time. when there is a single coordinate in `multitpoint_col`, this is throwing:

```
ERROR:  Geometry type (Point) does not match column type (MultiPoint)
```

why is this happening.

**One more thing:**

I would also like to discard the new appended coordinate if it already exists. Is this possible?

Comment: Convert the point into a multipoint with one member like `MULTIPOINT (( -10981893 3037470 ))`.

Comment: @user30184 same error

Comment: You can try the `ST_Multi()` function

Comment: In your edited question the WKT is wrong `'MULTIPOINT (4.49306 52.26167)'`.  It must be `'MULTIPOINT ((4.49306 52.26167))'`.

Comment: On a side note, you can remove all geom-to-text conversions, they are not needed and can have side effect (removing some decimals)

Answer (score 4):

To wrap this up:

```
UPDATE
  <table>
SET
  geom = ST_Multi(ST_Union(geom, 'SRID=4326;POINT(<lon|x>, <lat|y>)'))
WHERE
  id = <id>
;
```

All covered.

Comment: But this is throwing this error: ERROR:  lwgeom_union_prec: Operation on mixed SRID geometries (4326 != 0).

Comment: @bcsta you need to specify the SRID of that input geometry - see my update using the EWKT format. If you pass in coordinates into `ST_MakePoint`, wrap it in a call to `ST_SetSRID`.

Answer (score 0):

The query I am using is correct. The issue is that the coordinate I was trying to add was exactly identical to **the only other coordiante inside the multipoint column**.

This throws the error.

Comment: That does not match with the error message "ERROR:  Geometry type (Point) does not match column type (MultiPoint)".

Comment: @user30184 yes, `st_union` on a single multipoint will return a point, same if all inputs are the same

Comment: @bcsta it is not an issue. If you always want a multipoint you must wrap the st_union output into a `st_multi`